# ChoiceBox not setting ObservableList in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ChoiceBox in my JavaFx Application named choiceBoxPizza.

In my controller i declare it with:

```
@FXML 
private ChoiceBox choiceBoxPizza;
```

My function that contains some test data is:

```
private void fillChoiceBoxPizza(){
    try {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Pizza A");
        list.add("Pizza B");
        list.add("Pizza C");
        ObservableList obList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        choiceBoxPizza = new ChoiceBox<>(obList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

So the should be filled with the `list`. The strange thing is, that I do not get any exception and the choiceBox is after the call of the method still empty.

Is there a mistake in my logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
choiceBoxPizza = new ChoiceBox<>(obList);
```

with this one, it should work:

```
choiceBoxPizza.setItems(obList)
```

You should not initialize an element already declared in the `.fxml` file. [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to) is a more broader explanation on how the initialization process in JavaFX works.

Hope this helps